# Java - Arrays: How do i find the number that has a similar digit most times?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a problem with one of my tasks.
I was asked to build an array that the user will enter the length of.
At the end, the main goal is to print the number that has the largest frequency of any digit.
For example, if the length of the array is 4 and the numbers are: 1000, 212, 1345, 88818 - 
the number that should be printed is 88818 because it has more similar digits (the number 8 shows up 4 times).

I was convinced that what i had until now was good, but I find that the program is incomplete for two reasons:

1. If the size of the array is larger than 2, after creating the array nothing happens.
2. If one of the numbers has more than one digit again nothing happens.

I have been trying to figure out what is the problem for 5 hours now and still no luck.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Just to point out, I'm not allowed to use arrays that are not of type int[], and any material that is more advanced than arrays.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static void frequentNumber() {
     int num=0;
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Enter array size");
      num = in.nextInt();
      if (num >=1)
        break;
      }
    int[] a = createArray(num);
    int[] freq = new int[a.length]; //holds the frequency of each number in the primary array
    int count = 0, b;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        b=a[i];
        while (b > 0) { // counts the number of digits 
            count++;
            b/=10;   }
        int[] k = new int[count]; // array of digits
        b=a[i];
        for (int j=0; j<k.length; j++) { // enters each digit into it's own box at the digits array
            k[j] = b % 10;
            b /= 10;   }
        int[] sortedK = new int[k.length];
        sortedK = sortArray(k); // sorts the array with bubble sort
        int max=0, maxNew=0;
        for (int s=1; s < sortedK.length; s++) {
            if (sortedK.length == 1) {
                maxNew++;
                    break; }
                  else if (sortedK[s] != sortedK[s-1])
                max=0;
            while (sortedK[s] == sortedK[s-1]) {
                max++;
                if (max > maxNew)
                    maxNew=max; 
                   }    
           }                           
        freq[i] = maxNew;     /* at this point, maxNew will have the amount of max frequent digits
                                   for the number at a[i]*/
    }                                   
    int maxIndex = checkMaxIndex(freq); // This Method returns an int that is the index of the highest frequency;
    printArray(a);
    System.out.println("The number with most freq digit is: " + a[maxIndex]);
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this a pointer, but I would start by counting the digits in one integer!

```
/**
 * Take a decimal number as input, count the digits.
 * 
 * @param in
 *          A decimal number.
 * @return An array of 10 digit counts.
 */
public static int[] digitCounter(int in) {
  int[] ret = new int[10];
  String v = String.valueOf(in);
  for (char c : v.toCharArray()) {
    // You should probably use a 'switch' here.
    if (c == '0') {
      ret[0]++;
    } else if (c == '1') {
      ret[1]++;
    } else if (c == '2') {
      ret[2]++;
    } else if (c == '3') {
      ret[3]++;
    } else if (c == '4') {
      ret[4]++;
    } else if (c == '5') {
      ret[5]++;
    } else if (c == '6') {
      ret[6]++;
    } else if (c == '7') {
      ret[7]++;
    } else if (c == '8') {
      ret[8]++;
    } else if (c == '9') {
      ret[9]++;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: use `ret[c-'0']++` to avoid if's

Comment: @vandale That's a nice tip.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch Thanks for the advice. But I did not understand why did you set the  size of the array as 10? 
Isn't that assuming that there are 10 digits?
And if not, it would be great if you could explain it to me. Sorry if my questions are dumb, I'm just starting to learn.
 vandale thanks for the tip.